# Alternativa à Implementação JPA

Tags: java-ee, orm

Estou utilizando JPA em um projeto, com a implementação Hibernate, ainda utilizo o Java 7.

E constantemente a PermGen fica sem espaço. Sei que é por conta do Hibernate, como sou novo nessa tecnologia java. Alguém sabe indicar alguma implementação menos pesada para JPA. Fui usar o EclipseLink foi pior porque nem o deploy eu fiz.

Eu não queria aumentar o PermGen, queria uma solução e não um paliativo.

Já no Java 8 não estou com essa bronca porque não exite mais esse espaço, foi substituído pelo Metaspace, mesmo assim a aplicação cresce demais.

Alguma dica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

o Pessoal do [Batoo](http://batoo.org/) alega que é uma implementação leve e rápida. O código é aberto e você pode testar o Benchmark em https://github.com/BatooOrg/BatooJPABenchmark.

[Neste post](http://highscalability.com/blog/2012/10/9/batoo-jpa-the-new-jpa-implementation-that-runs-over-15-times.html) o autor diz que o Batto é 15 vezes mais rápido que o Hibernate.

Acho que vale uma tentativa.

Outra opção é abandonar o JPA e usar algo mais simples como o Pattern DAO (Data Acess Object) e neste caso dê uma olhada nesta implementação [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/). As vezes seu modelo de dados é complexo o suficiente e um Pattern DAO não resolve.

Answer (score 4):

Eu diria que seu problema está mais relacionado a como você usa o JPA do que o JPA como problema.

EclipseLink, Hibernate, OpenJPA ou Batoo vão continuar dando problema. Com Java8 você vai estourar a memória do mesmo modo, a diferneça é o tipo de erro que vai aparecer.

Esse erro aparece com o JPA quando você trás muitos dados para a memória. ***Esse erro também apareceria com JDBC muito facilmente***.

Algumas soluções para esse problema é:

1. Busca paginada - Ao invés de simplesmente trazer 15 mil resultados do banco de dados, traga apenas o que será exibido ao usuário
2. Evite relacionamentos anotados com @EAGER. Ao anotar relacionamentos com @EAGER você estará trazendo informações desnecessárias e com isso lotará a memória de modo desnecessário
3. Faça consultas específicas com JPQL. Se for necessário trazer dados de relacionamentos, crie uma JPQL para isso, por exemplo: `select c from Cachorro c join on c.pessoas p where c.id = 33` Note que com isso eu limito os dados que serão trazidos.
4. Traga seus objetos como detached. Você otimizar o uso do JPA caso seja apenas uma consulta 'read only' de informações. Com EJB use a transação NOT_SUPPORTED, com Spring @Transactional(readOnly = true) e se for transação manual não faça `entityManager.getTransaction().begin()`.

Agora, caso você queira abandonar o JPA você poderia dar uma olhada no MyBatis (http://www.mybatis.org/) ou QueryDSL (http://www.querydsl.com/)

Comment: Mas esse estouro da PermGen acontecia logo após o deploy, com 10 registro no banco, sei que a minha PermGen estava pequena mesmo. Contudo queria uma solução, para que os dados não aumentasse dessa forma.

Quanto a atulização dessas API eu gostei  da Querydsl, o iBatis eu já usei, mas queria uma ORM(automática).

Comment: @uaiHerbert, O Java8 não conta mais com a PermGen, agora é Metaspace, e o tamanho por padrão é o limite disponível em seu computador, sei que um dia a memória estourará.

Comment: Se você tem disponível toda a memória da máquina, no caso do Java8, não entendo qual o problema de aumentar o PermGen. Se com 10 objetos a memória já voa não creio que qualquer outro framework resolveria seu problema. Se você usar JDBC puro, talvez não com 10, mas a memória estourará do mesmo modo.

Comment: Se você buscar os objetos como detached o uso de memória diminuirá, mas ainda assim, não resolverá seu problema tendo um servidor com memória tão limitada.

Comment: Não, o estouro da memória não está relacionado à dados da aplicação, por exemplo: milhões de registros que eu busco do banco, esses milhões de objetos serão removidos pelo GC, o problema é que algumas API carregam muita classe da sua lib, e essas classes não registradas na PermGem(extinta no 8).
Mas, não é pq foi extinta na versão 8, que eu devo ficar tranquilizado, pois tem muitas aplicações que eu necessito de versões anteriores(no caso eu preciso).

Comment: Isso de fim da PermGen eu vejo como uma 'maqueação'. Mesmo no Java8 você também poderá limitar o tamanho da memória utilizada, que por padrão, essa opção não vem habilitada. Eu vejo que boa prática o correto é limitar o tamanho da memória e não deixar aberto para  uso infinito.

Comment: Duvido muito que sua aplicação carrege milhões de registros sem JPA e com apenas 10 registros já aconteça o estouro da memória. Creio que existe alguma má utilização aí.

Comment: Claro, por isso que estava à procura de uma alternativa ao Hibernate/JPA, pois não quero ficar aumentando minha PermGen apenas que eu possa utilizar o Hibernate.

E eu sei que essa mémoria:

1º Não está associada com os dados da aplicação.
2º O GC não tem acesso para coletar algum dados que foi registrado, nem mesmo limpar as classes carregadas(não tem sentido limpar as classes carregadas).
3º O Hibernate e EclipseLink carrega muitas classes.

Comment: Qualquer mapeamento ORM vai carregar classes para a memória. A não ser que bravamente eles queiram implementar a própria reflexão, que é algo que ñ ouvi sobre algum provider fazer.